# What's the cleanest way to add a decorator from a derived class to its base class?

Tags: python, class, python-decorators

I have a set of different classes that share most of their functionality. Their differences can be isolated in a single method and in the decorator to be applied to one of the base methods.

What's the cleanest for the derived classes to set this decorator, which has to be applied to a base class method? I tried something along these lines, but it didn't work, as the method to be decorated was already bound:

```
class Base(other):
    decorator = lambda x:x

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.post = self.decorator(self.post)
        super(Base, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def post(self):
        pass

class Derived(Base):
    decorator = some_decorator
```

Comment: Your question isn't really clear.  In what way did it not work?  Can you give an example of what you want to happen?  Are you saying the derived classes should inherit the base class method, but with different decorators?

Comment: Derived classes are used for inheriting stuff from base class, and you're trying to do other way around.

Comment: @hcwhsa: He's trying to override base class behavior, which is a perfectly reasonable thing to do in a subclass. It's not the most common way to do it, but it's not backward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short version is: What you want here is effectively the same thing as a static method, and that's the easiest way to solve it.

---

The problem isn't that the method, `self.post`, is bound, but that the decorator, `self.decorator`, is.

When you store a function as a class attribute, that's basically the same thing as defining a new method. So accessing it as `self.decorator` is going to get you a bound method. (If you don't understand why, either read the [Descriptor HowTo](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html), or take it on faith.) Which means it will be called with that `self` as its first argument.

You could always add an explicit `self` parameter to `decorator` and just ignore it… but if you want a method without a `self` parameter, that's exactly what a static method is: something that, when used as a method, doesn't take a magic `self`. So:

```
class Derived(Base):
    @staticmethod
    def decorator(func):
        whatever(fund)
```

… or:

```
class Derived(Base):
    decorator = staticmethod(whatever)
```

---

If you really want to look up `decorator` as a data attribute even though it's a function, the easy way is to move it to the instance:

```
class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.decorator = whatever
        super(Derived, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Or, of course, you can reverse the descriptory methodness:

```
self.post = self.decorator.im_func(self.post)
```

… or just avoid it by doing the lookup manually:

```
decorator = type(self).__dict__['decorator']
self.post = decorator(self.post)
```

These are all hacky, but then you're trying to do something hacky, so I don't think it's a problem that the hackiness is explicit.